# Have to create 2d array (4x4) array and has to fill the diagnal with 1s and rest of the spaces with 0s

Tags: arrays

```
    public class sampleq8
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int size =4;
        int array[][]=new int[size][size];
        for(int i=0; i<array.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++)
            {
                array[0][0]=1;
            }
            //array[4][4]=1;
        //  array[

            System.out.println(array[i][i]);
        }
    }
}
```

i got to print out the first column correctly i cant produce the rest of the rows or the columns i need some suggestions please thanks.

Comment: What language is this?  Can you update your post and add the appropriate tags?

Answer (score 1):

Java initializes all the values of your array to 0 automatically, you only need to assign values to the diagonal.

```
int size =4;        
    int array [][] = new int[size][size];
    for (int i =0;i<size;i++){
        array[i][i]=1;
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

This does the job.
In your version you are only setting the value 1 to the element with coordinates 0,0 in your array

To print your array you need to `import java.util.Arrays;`

This one will print the matrix nicely

```
for (int i =0 ;i<4;i++){System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[i]));}
```

Comment: this is only printing it down not like rows and columns

Comment: 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1

Comment: It should technically print this: [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]] which is the inner structure of your array. It is not going to print you the matrix nicely, of course. For that you can iterate again through the array, doing:  for (int i =0 ;i<4;i++) {System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[i]));}

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment is always using the 0,0 element.

```
array[0][0]=1
```

You need to set the assignment like this:

```
array[i][j]=1
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, dont know if it works, i cant run it right now

```
for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
{
 array[i][i] = 1;
}
for(int i=0; i<array.length;i++)
{
 for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++)
 {
  if(array[i][j] != 1)
  array[i][j]=0;
 }
}
```